# Tensor product and Cartesian product

Tags: elementary-set-theory, tensor-products

All the time, I encounter some literature on this it doesn't clarify a couple of things.

Firstly when is Tensor product applicable and when not ? Similarly for the Cartesian product (I think more generally a direct product). How does one know where to use a tensor product or Cartesian product. I would like to understand it better with examples.

I know that Cartesian product is something like, given two sets $A = \{1,2,6\}$ and $B = \{3,5\}$, the Cartesian product is 
$$ A \times B = \{(1,3),(1,5),(2,3),(2,5),(6,3),(6,5),\} $$
Now, can we define $A \otimes B$ ? If yes, how does it look ?

Comment: Often you are tensoring vector spaces, with the intent to make a multiplication like behavior out of it, much like direct sum is like addition of vector spaces. I'm not sure if it makes sense to take a tensor product of sets without any other structure.. Maybe someone not knowledgeable can chime in.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/710481/what-is-the-difference-between-cartesian-and-tensor-product-of-two-vector-spaces.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, it doesn't make any sense to talk about $A \otimes B$; generally we construct tensor products out of two modules over a commutative ring $R$. So your sets $A$ and $B$ need some more underlying algebraic structure to define a tensor product - they both need to be closed under addition, and also by left (/right) multiplication by elements of $R$.

Examples you might often see are the tensor product of two vector spaces, but this is just a special case of the above, since a vector space is just a module over a field.

Comment: Can you give me an example of tensor product over two Linear Vector Space(LVS). Also, can I take Cartesian product of two LVS ? If yes, what is difference between both ?

Comment: +1, thanks for the hint about defining tensor products only for algebraic structures !!

Comment: LVS? Afraid I'm not sure what that that acronym is!

Comment: Sorry !! edited the first comment.

Comment: It's quite late and I can't think of any interesting examples with vector spaces. General results would be things like $\mathbb{R}^n \otimes \mathbb{R}^m \cong \mathbb{R}^{nm}$ viewed as $\mathbb{R}$ vector spaces. The more interesting examples I can think of off the top of my head are tensor products of abelian groups ($\mathbb{Z}$ modules) where we have $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z} \not\cong \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ where $d =(m,n)$. Hopefully someone will provide a more enlightening example for vector spaces

Answer (score 1):

The construction of the tensor product is really motivated by bilinear maps.  There is an article by Tim Gowers (https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~wtg10/tensors3.html) named "How to Lose Your Fear of Tensor Products."  It may take a little time to read through it, but I can promise you that you really will lose any fear of tensor products afterwards.